# How to remove an empty object from a json file

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, object, jq

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
[
    [
        [
            {
                "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
                "id": "10000",
                "self": "https://test.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/10000",
                "key": "AGILE-1",
                    "components": [],
                    "timetracking": {}

            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

I'd like to remove the empty arrays like timetracking and components.

I was reading a lot on line and tried different things, but I only manage to remove null or empty values, but the whole array or object.

This is what I tried:

```
cat $FilePathOrigin | jq-win64.exe -sc 'fromstream(tostream | select(length == 1 or .[1] != null))' > $FilePathDestiny
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the whole key and value, or replace the value with something else?

Comment: Timetracking is not an array

Comment: yes, I'd like to remove the keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As observed in the comments, it's not entirely clear what you want, but if you want to remove the keys that have values equal to [] or {}, then you could use `walk` like so:

```
walk(if type == "object" 
     then with_entries(if .value == {} or .value == [] then empty else . end) 
     else . end)
```

This can also be written more compactly as:

```
walk(if type == "object" then with_entries(select(.value | (. != {} and . != []))) else . end)
```

If you only want to remove keys from specific objects, then the simplest would probably be to use `with_entries` as above.

### Warning about `length`

`length` is not only defined on arrays and objects!

Comment: I'm getting an error, but this might not be related to the statement. I'm running it in powershell and getting: 
     object/0 is not defined at <top-level>

Comment: To avoid issues related to command-line escapes, consider using jq’s -f command-line option.